# how to maintain state of an ajax request and its loading state of a React component after it unmounts

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering if there's a way to persist state of a component that will unmount and possibly remount in the example of a dropdown that has a `download` option, which will then close the dropdown upon selection, which will cause the option to unmount and a spinner will load.

Right now, I'm keeping all of the state of the related dropdown option in its parent and passing it back down to the option via props and would rather have that logic stored in a custom hook or something cleaner.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [setDataToDownload, dataToDownload] = useState();
  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && <Spinner />}
      <Dropdown>
        {({ close }) =>
          options.map(op => (
            <ChildOption
              isLoading={isLoading}
              setDataToDownload={setDataToDownload}
              dataToDownload={dataToDownload}
              setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
              close={close}
              op={op}
            />
          ))
        }
      </Dropdown>
    </>
  );
};

const ChildOption = ({ close, isLoading, setIsLoading }) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={async () => {
        close();
        setIsLoading(true);
        const data = await fetchSomeStuff();
        setDataToDownload(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }}
    >
      {op.name}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> if there's a way to persist state of a component that will unmount.

States of components are destroyed, when they are unmounted. So, you cannot access or retrieve state of an unmounted component. **Unless, you store the state somewhere else.**

You can use `Redux`, as a global state. You can dispatch an action from `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method to store your current state in Redux `store`. And, you can retrieve it back in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

Other than Redux, you can use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store component's state. Make use of `componentWillUnmount` and `componentDidMount` lifecycle methods as I explained above.